# Excel file extension save not working in Postman but works in Swagger

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core-mvc, postman, swagger-ui

Code in use :

```
[Route("DownloadFile")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DownloadFile(inputdata)
{
   try
    {
       data=//getdata;
        if (data)
        {
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                wb.Worksheets.Add(data);
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(stream);
                    return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Excel File.xlsx");
                }
            }
        }
        else
            return Ok("No data");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       
    }
}
```

This is the controller file (.netcore mvc) . The call works fine and I am able to download the file properly as "Excel File.xlsx" when called from Swagger but in postman it saves the file as "all files" and not with xlsx extension by default.

I tried

1. SSL certificate verification off
2. "Send and Download" while calling the API
3. made the call as GET rather POST
4. Accept type as "application/vnd.ms-excel".

Please help as to how can I save the file by default via postman call as Excel File.xlsx rather just Excel File without any extension.

Comment: What's the actual question? What happens when you actually *save* the file? Does the extension change? That's a [POSTMAN issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2082) anyway and  doesn't affect browsers or other callers.

Comment: postman is not saving the file with any extension. Whatever type is sent in content type or Accept type it simply ignores it and saves as "File" type.

Comment: That's a POSTMAN bug. You can't fix that by changing the header or anything else.